# why is this else block executed twice?

Tags: c, for-loop, if-statement

I have the following code which correctly calculates the jaccard similarity between an input `char array` and an existing array of char arrays. `jacc_sim_rec[]` is used to record the similarities which satisfy a minimum threshold value. The for loop is used to iterate through the multidimensional array and the loop is supposed to continue checking similarity if minimum threshold is not satisfied at `if (jacc_sim < SIM_THRESHOLD);`   else record the result at

```
else
    {
        jacc_sim_rec[j] = jacc_sim;//keep record of similarity
        ++j;//record number of highly similar elements
    }
```

my problem is, the whole statements in the  `else` block is executed twice every time the threshold value is satisfied.

```
int j=0;

void calc_jac_sim( char*INCOMING, int grp)
{
    unsigned long i, j11 = 0, j01 = 0, j10 = 0,m=0;
    char *m11, *m01, *m10;
    float jacc_sim = 0.0;
    char r1[SBF_LEN] = { NULL };
    char r2[SBF_LEN] = { NULL };
    char r3[SBF_LEN] = { NULL };
    int cnt = SBF_LEN - 1;

    clear_jacc_sim_info();

    for (int i = 0; i <= SBF_REC[grp]; ++i)
    {
        while (cnt >= 0)
        {
            r1[cnt] = SBF[grp][i][cnt] & INCOMING[cnt];
            r2[cnt] = ~SBF[grp][i][cnt] & INCOMING[cnt];
            r3[cnt] = SBF[grp][i][cnt] & ~INCOMING[cnt];
            cnt--;
        }
        m11 = ( char*)r1;
        m01 = ( char*)r2;
        m10 = ( char*)r3;

        for (m = SBF_LEN * sizeof( char); m--;
             j11 += NumberOfSetBits(*m11++),
                 j01 += NumberOfSetBits(*m01++),
                 j10 += NumberOfSetBits(*m10++));

        jacc_sim = j11 / (float)(j11 + j01 + j10);

        if (jacc_sim < SIM_THRESHOLD);
        //continue;//do nothing
        else
        {
            jacc_sim_rec[j] = jacc_sim;//keep record of similarity
            ++j;//record number of highly similar elements
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What makes you think it's happening twice on the same iteration, not just two different iterations?

Comment: Instead of `if(jacc_sim < SIM_THRESHOLD); // do nothing else {...}` why don't you just write `if(jacc_sim >= SIM_THRESHOLD) { ... }`

Comment: I debugged it @Barmar

Comment: Can you add the transcript of your debugging session to the question? Because what you're claiming is really hard to believe.

Comment: Not sure if it's relevant, but the `while(cnt >= 0)` loop will only be executed on the first iteration of the `for` loop. After that, `cnt` will still be `0`, so it won't go into the loop.

Comment: And totally unrelated, but you don't need the casts in `(char *)r1`, etc. Arrays automatically decay to pointers when you're assigning them.

Comment: What Barmar said is also true for the bit counts `j11`, `j01`and `j10`. You should make these and ´cnt` local to the body of the loop over `i`.and initialise them for each pass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand the code, but I'll bet the problem is that you're not reinitializing `cnt` each time through the `for` loop, so you only fill in `r1`, `r2`, and `r3` when `i = 0`.

Change that loop to:

```
    for (int cnt = SBF_LEN - 1; cnt >= 0; cnt--)
    {
        r1[cnt] = SBF[grp][i][cnt] & INCOMING[cnt];
        r2[cnt] = ~SBF[grp][i][cnt] & INCOMING[cnt];
        r3[cnt] = SBF[grp][i][cnt] & ~INCOMING[cnt];
    }
```

I'm also not sure why this needs to count down instead of up, like a typical loop, but it shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: the reason for the count down is following a recommendation from the stackoverflow community, which said "count down in for loops is faster than up".

Comment: [Premature optimization is the root of all evil](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization)

Comment: That may be true, but only if you can save the update stage and compare for non-zero: `for (i = n; i--; )`. Anyway, such micro-opimizations usually don't account for much.

Comment: @George If you can, please erase that piece of "advice" from your mind.  And anyone who's in the habit of spreading such advice, please *stop*.  Overall, the number of cases where this optimization will actually lead to a measurable performance improvement, in a program where it matters, is minuscule.  By contrast, the number of programs that will accrue real bugs due to blind application of this advice is nonzero and much larger.  It's a little like telling people not to wear seatbelts because they might not be able to get out of a wreck in a fire -- which is true, maybe one time on 1,000.